# Android Bitmap won't scale

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I tried scaling a picture and it worked well at first, but when scaling down alot it doesn't seem to work. After a while it stops scaling down. I can't get the number of bytes to be less than 630 with quality 0. I realize that this is a shit picture, but I want to scale it down alot and it simply doesn't work. Any idea would be appreciated.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    int width = bitmap.getWidth(); //3920
    int height = bitmap.getHeight(); //2204

    float scale = 0.0034; //usually calculated in runtime but set for simplicity now.

    // Resize the bitmap
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

    // Recreate the new bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, out);

    return out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rectangle to rescale your bitmap

```
Rect srcrect = new Rect(0,0,yourbitmap.getWidth(),yourbitmap.getHeight());
Rect destrect = new Rect(startindexxright,startindexyright,startindexxleft,startindexyleft);
canvas.drawBitmap(yourbitmap, srcrect,destrect, null);
```

srcrect is a rectangle where you have to input details of your bitmap and destrect is the area of your device display(the portion in which you want to display the image).

Comment: Thanks but I need to scale it down because I need to send it over network and I have strict size limitations. Can I use the rectangle to scale it and then get a byte array from that?

Answer (score 0):

Check [BitmapFactory.Options.InSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

This code reduces a Bitmap stored in a File, but it should be easy to adapt the code to a in-memory Bitmap

```
 public static Bitmap getReducedBitmap(Context context, String path) {    
    File bitmapFile = new File(path);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(bitmapFile);
    InputStream in = null;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    try {
      in = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

      // Decode image size
      BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
      BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
      in.close();

      //scale works better with powers of 2
      int scale = 1;
      while ((options.outWidth * options.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > WSConfig.PICTURE_MAX_PIXELS) {
        scale++;
      }

      Bitmap reducedBitmap = null;
      in = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
      if (scale > 1) {
        // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
        // larger than target
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = scale;
        reducedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);    
      } else {
        reducedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
      }
      in.close();

      return reducedBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("UTILS", e.getMessage(), e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

My MAX_PICTURE_PICTURES determines the max resolution